# Как в React отменить отправку формы?

Tags: reactjs

Сделал форму на React пытаюсь получить из нее данные, ставлю на функцию в событии `onSubmit` `e.preventDefault` и страничка один фиг перезагружается. Что я делаю не правильно? Попробовал сделать простую форму и тоже ничего не работает https://codepen.io/Shub1nk/pen/ZMEEdY

Answer (score 1):

событие onSubmit нужно вешать на форму а не на кнопку, тогда все работает

...